# Laravel hasManyThrough relation not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Consider I have three tables as shown below,

1. projects-
   id,
   name
2. environments-
   id,
   project_id,
   environment_id
3. deployments-
   id,
   commit_hash

Here, project id and deployment id are stored in environments. Environments and deployments have multiple rows for same project.
If I have project id, how will be the laravel eloquent relation.

I tried following code but not working.
`return $this->hasManyThrough(Deployment::class, Environment::class);`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In project model try to add this method and you will get all the deployments with environment

```
public function deploymentWithEnv()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('deployments', 'environments', 'id', 'environment_id');
}
```

Second is user pivot concept "withpivot", this will be in project model

```
public function deploymentWithEnv()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Deployment::class, Environment::class, 
      'project_id', 'environment_id');
}

public function deployments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Deployment::class);
}
```

Last in controller use "withPivot"